# Two equidistant points from a random coordinate without breaking cavas constraints

Tags: javascript, math

My variables are:

- `canvasX` - This is the horizontal size of the canvas being drawn on. (user picks)
- `1stX` - My first point, determined at random, within `canvasX`. (something like: `random(0, canvasX)`)
- `rando` - A random number to determine the distance the next 2 points are from `1stX`.
- `2ndXleft` - an equidistant point from `1stX` to the left. (basically `1stX - rando`)
- `2ndXright` - an equidistant point from the 1stX to the right. (basically `1stX + rando`)

I've got a canvas I'm drawing on and I want a point picked out with a random variable for x. I then want two more points but these need to have the x coordinate be equidistant from the first. I also want for these points to always be within the canvas.

So, if my canvas size is 1000, and my `1stX` is 100, the max distance for `rando` would have to be 100. same is my `1stX` was 900.

`rando` is my problem, how do I figure out what that distance can be?

Comment: `rando`must be less than `min(1stX, canvasX-1stX)`

Comment: This works. You can post it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would possibly be the following

```js
const canvasX = 1000;
const firstX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasX);
const limit = Math.min(firstX, canvasX - firstX);
const offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);

console.log(firstX, limit, offset)
console.log(firstX - offset, firstX + offset);
```

So the following will always be true

```
0 <= firstX - offset <= firstX <= firstX + offset < canvasX
```